# Is there a neat way to find the sign of a real function with radicals like this?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

This simple function:

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x+2} - 2\sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{x}$$

is negative for $x>0$ (just checked out with a graphic calculator). 
**But how to "prove" this algebraically?**

The function comes out from the problem of finding which of these numbers $\sqrt{12} - \sqrt{11}$ and $\sqrt{11} - \sqrt{10}$ is bigger.

[BTW, given that $f(x)$ is negative, it should be that $\sqrt{11} - \sqrt{10}$ is bigger than $\sqrt{12} - \sqrt{11}$ !]

Thanks!

Comment: Since you have the tag "real analysis", do you know about differentiation and integration? Because that would give an elegant answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sqrt{x+2}-2\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}\\
&= \sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x+1}-(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x})\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+1}}-\frac1{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\\
&<0
\end{align}

since $x+2 > x$.

Comment: (+1) You were too fast for me.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! Is this a "standard pattern" to solve these kind of problems? I'm not a mathematician :)

Comment: I think It's natural when we see subtraction of square root, we think of conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

I will prove $f(x)<0$

So i need to prove $\sqrt{x+2}-2\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}<0\left(x>0\right)$

Or $\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x}<2\sqrt{x+1}$

By square both sides we have: $\sqrt{x^2+2x}<x+1$

Or $x^2+2x<x^2+2x+1\Leftrightarrow0<1$

So $f(x)<0$ it means  $f(x)$ is negative for $x>0$

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

*With some analysis*

The square root function is *strictly concave*, hence
$$\sqrt{\tfrac12 x+\tfrac12(x+2)}=\sqrt{x+1}>\tfrac12\sqrt x+\tfrac12\sqrt{x+2}\iff \sqrt x+\sqrt{x+2}<2\sqrt{x+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a calculus-based answer, that I find more intuitive. We want to prove that
$$
\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x} > \sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{x + 1}.
$$

Fix $x > 0$. Then the fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that what we want to prove is equivalent to
$$
\int_{x}^{x+1} \frac1{2\sqrt{y}} \mathrm dy > \int_{x+1}^{x+2} \frac1{2\sqrt{y}} \mathrm dy.
$$
But because the function $\sqrt{y}$ is strictly increasing, the function $\frac1{2\sqrt{y}}$ is strictly decreasing. In particular, integrating over an interval of length one gives lower numbers as the lower bound of said interval increases.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. If I had to explain the solution of the problem to an high school student, I would not be sure to go your way :). But anyway... quite elegant indeed.

Answer (score 0):

$(x+2)^{1/2}-(x+1)^{1/2}  - ((x+1)^{1/2} -x^{1/2})$.

MVT:

$(x+k+1)^{1/2}-(x+k)^{1/2}=$

$(1/2)(\frac{1}{a})^{1/2}×1,$ where

$a \in (x+k, x+k+1)$.

Compare the terms for $k=0,1$

Used:

$\dfrac {f(x)-f(x_o)}{x-x_o}=f'(a)$, where

$a \in (\min(x_0,x),\max(x_0,x))$.